# Dividing FFT into several bins containing dominant peaks and finding energy in these bins

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I've generated FFTs for a set of signals in time domain at different deflections. I want to find in which frequency range the signal is more sensitive. Can someone help me do the following since I'm new to programming and signal processing??

- So I want to select a frequency range in which all the dominant peaks
  are coming .

[image: FFT plot of signals]
*( In this case [FFT plot of signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFu3c.png), by looking at the figure, the frequency
   range to be considered would be somewhere between 35000Hz-125000Hz
   (Is there a way to automatically find this ?) Also I don't know where
   to fix the threshold.)*

- Divide it into a number of bins (not more than 10) in such a way that
  each peak should fall completely within one of these bins. (bins need
  not be of equal length and should be same for all signals)
- Then, calculate the energy for each bin in each signal. Then plot curves
  for each bin showing the variation of energy in each bin with respect
  to deflection. (ie. deflection on x-axis and area under curve on y
  axis.)

Following is the code I'm using for getting FFT (also attached the set of time domain signals and deflection [data](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/80468/amplitude_deflection.mat)):

```
[m, n]= size(amp); % amp- amplitude data
t=linspace(0,5000,n); % time
Fs=2000000;
for i=1:m
  L = n;
  NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
  UT = fft(amp(i,:),NFFT)/L;
  f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2);
  ft(i,:) = zeros(1,NFFT/2);
  ft(i,:) = UT(1:NFFT/2);
  mag(i,:) = 2*abs(ft(i,:));
end;
figure
for i=1:m
  plot(f,mag(i,:))
  hold on;
end;
  xlabel('Frequency (Hz)','fontsize',12)
  ylabel('Magnitude','fontsize',12)
  title('Frequency Spectrum of recieved signals','fontsize',14)
  axis([0,150000,0,4])
  legend(arrayfun(@(deflection) ['Deflection = ',num2str(deflection),'\mum'],deflection,'Uni',0));
  set(gcf, 'Color', 'w');
```